# nodejs memory buffer synchronized .pipe()

Tags: node.js, stream, buffer, pdfkit

I am trying to migrate pdfkit from png-js to pngsj2, because png-js doesn't support interlaced png. I need to load PNG file in a sync way. I try to do it this way:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    PNG = require('pngjs2').PNG;
var stream = require('stream');
var bufferStream = new stream.PassThrough();
var buf = fs.readFileSync('./logs/rid12.png');
bufferStream.end(buf);
var png = null;
bufferStream.pipe(new PNG())
    .on('parsed', function() {
        console.log("here");
        png = this;
    });

console.log("there",png);
```

"there" happens before "here", so png is null. Is it possible to pipe inmemory buffer to PNG parser so that I don't have to make callback architecture?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to make a async method synchronous.

There are librarys such as https://github.com/scriby/asyncblock which may be able to fake it.

```
asyncblock(function(flow) {

    var png = null
    flow.sync( bufferStream.pipe(new PNG())
      .on('parsed', function() {
        console.log("here");
        png = this;
        flow.callback()
      })
    );

   // png not null
});
```

Comment: I don't think so. Probably it is possible to call some method of (new PNG()), but I don't know which one.